# How to start a bounty on question with outdated answers but having low reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

There are some interesting questions having outdated answers. So, instead of making a duplicate I usually start a bounty, costing me at least 50 points from the reputation each time. Of course, the idea behind that is that people just have to think before doing this. Therefore, next bounty worth increases by 50, right? Although I don't know if the questioner and all answerers are getting notified in such case of a bounty. This would clearly disturbing if every minute someone could issue a bounty.

However, I feel a bit penalized in searching my question and then have to pay to get not outdated answers without gaining anything back, which I assume (correct me if I am wrong).

So how do I start a bounty for outdated questions when having low rep.?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is being asked here.

Comment: Modified title and some text to emphasize my point. Ok?

Comment: If you don't have enough reputation to add a bounty to a question, *you can't add a bounty to that question*. Simple as that. You can't spend reputation points you don't have.

Comment: But what Do I do then? Ask the same question beeing redirected to the old as exact duplicate? Flag the question?

Comment: No, do *not* ask the same question when you already *know* it is a duplicate. Don't flag the question, either (What would the flag reason be??). Sometimes it might be appropriate to edit the question, which 'bumps' it. Could you post a link to the question you have in mind?

Comment: Also, if you find that this is happening *very frequently*, I might suggest there's another problem happening here... perhaps the questions are not being answered because they are not clear/specific enough to be answered, at all. Again; knowing what question(s) you have in mind here would be helpful.

Comment: Its more a general issue. I observed me from time to time that I found questions I want to ask that have already been asked but 2 years before. So I started a bounty. But unfortunately my reputation has decreased dramatically, so in near future I won't be able to start new bounties for outdated questions. So I feel penalized, since I contribute to keep the answers current. Its not frequently having, nor is special to a certain bounty I issued yet. All the questions are very well answered but as time goes by new solutions appear and make the other outdated. Its only about out-dating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short and plain answer is: you can't do that.

But I do understand what you mean and share your frustration.

My $0.02 in this case:

1. If your question is not *exactly* like the question already asked, just similar in some manners, ask new question and refer to the existing question, explaining why it's different. This is considered acceptable.
2. If your question is exactly like the old question with outdated answers feel free to call for help here on Meta. I know some people won't agree with me, but for example you can edit your own question here adding link to the question you think have outdated answer and I'm pretty sure there are users roaming Meta with enough reputation to spend so they'll start a bounty calling for new answers. After all, it's for the good of the community to have relevant and good answers.